# Print Excel from Java Directly to Print Server

Tags: java, excel, printing

We have an Java Application which generates Excel file from the application. I am looking for a solution which would help me to print the excel file directly to Print server which is Linux base.

Let me know what approaches are available to perform the same.

Comment: You can't simply send an Excel file to a printer. Excel itself prints as PCL. Also what should be printed from the Excel file? There are possibly multiple sheets in the workbook. So the simplest way would be creating PDF or PS with the same content as the Excel and print this.

Answer (score 0):

there is java API to do that called Print Service you can use it as follows

```
       PrintService defaultPrintService =  PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
       DocPrintJob printerJob = defaultPrintService.createPrintJob();
       File pdfFile = new File("yourfile");
       SimpleDoc simpleDoc = null;

       try {
           simpleDoc = new SimpleDoc(pdfFile.toURL(), DocFlavor.URL.AUTOSENSE, null);
       } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
           printerJob.print(simpleDoc, null);
       } catch (PrintException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: try it, I never use it for excel but it work for pdf

Comment: Ok. Trying the same now.

Comment: Tried the same. It prints wired characters on the Paper.